# Как проверить, сколько строк заданного текста заканчиваются знаком переноса строки?

Tags: python

Задание заключается в том, чтобы проверить, сколько строк заданного текста заканчиваются знаком переноса строки.

Но данный код всегда выдает 0, а если попробовать считать другие символы то все работает.

```py
def count_lines(text):
    lines = text.split('\n')
    count = 0
    
    for line in lines:
        if line.endswith('\n'):
            count += 1
    
    return count
    
file_path = '../labka2kurs/F1.txt'

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text1 = file.read()
    result = count_lines(text1)
    
print(result)
```

пример текста:

```
Сообщество здесь, чтобы помочь вам 
с конкретными проблемами по 
программированию, алгоритмам, 
языкам программирования.
```

Comment: Можно ведь просто посчитать количество строк, или я не прав?

Comment: _знаком переноса_ или _знаком переноса строки_?

Comment: Так в lines уже строки без \n.

Comment: `def count_strings(text: str) -> int:
    return len(text.split('\n'))`

Comment: вы же сами удаляете знаки переноса строки.  а потом пытаетесь их посчитать. не надо split. надо count("\n")

Comment: @strawdog можно пожалуйска пример

Comment: text.count("\n")

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто посчитать '\n'

```
with open ('F1.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    print(f.read().count('\n'))
```

или удалить пустые строки, а потом считать

```
with open ('F1.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    print(len([i for i in f.read().split('\n') if i]))
```

Comment: зачем удалять пустые строки? Об этом в задании ничего нет. Пустая строка тоже строка.

Answer (score 0):

Каждая строка заканчивается символом перевода строки. Следовательно символов перевода строк в файле ровно столько, сколько строк. Поэтому достаточно посчитать количество строк.

```
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text1 = file.readlines() # читает файл в список построчно
print(len(text1)) # длина списка = количество строк = количество символов перевода строки
```

Answer (score 0):

Объект файла при итерации по нему отдаёт отдельные строки, следовательно:

```py
with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(len(list(f)))
```